# Dynamically changing dropdown to textfield opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, vqmod

I am trying to change a drop down so that a user can add a custom input instead.
I am using VQMod and have currently set up a PHP array as follows:

```
<td><select name="electricColours">
               <?php foreach (array("", "White", "Black", "Add Custom Colour..." ) as $eColours) { ?>
                 <?php if ($electricColours == $eColours) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $eColours;?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $electricColours; ?></option>
                 <?php } else { ?>
                   <option value="<?php echo $eColours;?>"><?php echo $eColours; ?></option>
                 <?php }?>
              <?php } ?>
              <td class="left"><a onclick="AddCustomColour();" class="button"><?php echo "Add Custom Colours"; ?></a></td>
              </select>
```

How would I be able to add new values to the eColours using the "Add Custom Colour..." so that the user inputs something and that colour is added on to the array.

I thought using Javascript so that it shows up as an alert and the user gets to choose their option would work however it keeps saying the variable is not defined.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
                function AddCustomColour()
                {
                    var colour=prompt("Please add custom colour","Silver");
                    var arrays =  <?php echo json_encode($electricColours); ?>;
                    if (colour!=null)
                    {
                        electricColours.push(colour);
                    }
                }
        </SCRIPT>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM API:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.setAttribute("value", value);
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
document.getElementById("the_select_element").appendChild(option);
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("the_select_element")
```

You could do something like:

```
document.forms.the_form.electricColours
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
                function AddCustomColour()
                {
                    var colour=prompt("Please add custom colour","Silver");
                    var arrays =  <?php echo json_encode($electricColours); ?>;
                    if (colour!=null)
                    {
                        electricColours.push(colour);
                    }
                }
        </SCRIPT>
```

With this Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddCustomColour()
{
    var colour=prompt("Please add custom colour","Silver");
    var ob = $("#electricColours");
    if (colour!=null)
    {
        ob.prepend("<option value="+ val +">" + text + "</option>");

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Console results: Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined. I believe you mean colour

Comment: val is the value of the prompt change it with "colour"

Comment: Sorry is prepend a jQuery function?

Comment: yes, prepend() is a jquery function. Check out in [link]http://api.jquery.com/prepend/